# Slide half the screen off on SlidingMenu

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm using [a SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) for Android

Is there a way that I can make it slide only half the screen not all the way to the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(offsetValue);
```

where `offsetValue` determines how far the menu goes. If you want to have it go half the screen, first get your screedWidth, then divide by 2 and pass the value to setBehindOffset().

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I want